# Magento, problem with adding a custom css file

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I am new with Magento.

By following instruction found in here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css-themes.html

For me no success to add a css file.

This is what I have done:

> app/code/MYVendor/mytheme/etc/module.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
  <module name="MYVendor_mytheme" setup_version="1.0.0">
    <sequence>
      <module name="Magento_Theme"/>
    </sequence>
  </module>
</config>
```

> app/code/MYVendor/mytheme/registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
  \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
  'MYVendor_mytheme',
  __DIR__ );
```

> app/design/frontend/MYVendor/mytheme/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
  <head>
    <css src="css/styles-l.css" media="screen and (min-width: 768px)"/>
  </head>
</page>
```

> app/design/frontend/MYVendor/mytheme/web/css/styles-l.css

```
body {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

I also have run:

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

But no luck.

Can anybody help me please! Thank!

Answer (score 0):

1. You need active your theme in dashboard(`content -> Design -> Configuration`).
2. If you active your theme, refresh the site cache in dashboard(`System -> Cache Management`), and `Ctrl+F5` to refresh your browser cache.